# Validar dos modelos en una misma vista en RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

tengo el modelo

**chofer**

nombre

edad

sexo

tipo_licencia

y el modelo

**vehiculo**

marca

modelo

anno

tipo

*cada modelo tiene su controlador y sus vistas, lo dos cumplen el CRUD (Create, Read, Update and Delete).*

Pero yo necesito que en un determinado momento de emergencia al crearse un nuevo chofer, se ingrese en la misma vista los datos de un vehículo no registrado y que la vista pueda hacer las validaciones de los modelos en la misma forma y salvar los dos modelos.

Alguna idea como se puede hacer esto???

Comment: Busca en internet como usar `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. También puedes ver ejemplos o servir como guía [las preguntas que han hecho en SOes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=accepts_nested_attributes_for) sobre dicho término.

Comment: El tema amigo @alter_lagos es que los modelos no son padre e hijo, por lo tanto no se pueden anidar, son modelos independientes de muchos a muchos

Comment: ¿Cómo es la vista para crear un nuevo chofer? Si ya tienes los campos del formulario para un nuevo vehículo lo puedes leer a través de `params` en el controlador y, dependiendo si tienes o no información en esos campos, creas el vehículo. ¿Podrías mostrar el código de la vista? Sobre eso podría darte un ejemplo.

Comment: @AlterLagos Ya consegui un ejemplo que me sirvio, muchas gracias por tus respuestas.